# Why Redmine web application encountered an internal error when Passenger server tried to start it?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, bundler

I intended to run Redmine web application on CentOS 7.5 server running Apache and Phusion passenger.

After installing and configuring the whole thing, when I accessed http:// in the web browser, I got a message that said

> Error starting web application

After I enabled `PassengerFriendlyErrorPages` in the virtualhost config file and restarted apache, I got the following error report:

```
The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application. But the application itself (and not Passenger) encountered an internal error.

Error details:

cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:86:in `load_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:116:in `block in <module:App>'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:115:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:28:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:

```
Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:86:in `load_app'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:116:in `block in <module:App>'
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:115:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:28:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

My virtualhost config file goes like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName x.x.x.x
    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine-3.4/public
    PassengerEnabled on 
    PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
    PassengerRoot /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    PassengerUser root
```

Even when I changed the PassengerRuby file path to ``/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby`, I got a 404 Page Not Found error.

My Setup is as follows:

- `rvm -v`: 1.29.4
- `ruby -v`: 2.5.1
- `rubygem -v`: 2.7.7
- `passenger -v`: 5.3.5
- `bundler -v`: 1.16.5
- `mariadb -v`: 10.3.9

Sorry I'm new to ruby & passenger; started on it only last week. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: What is your rails environment?

Comment: It is production ,i.e. RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: I think you are missing `PassengerEnv production` in Apache config